# Express Router Handling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, router

I'm currently using express to handle client request. At one point I need to handle get request if user loads any page of my app. So, I want all the routes to be configured at some place.
For example:
"/about"
"/contact"
"/listing"
"/product"

Above there are multiple routes and for each route I need to write app.get('/about', handler)..like this. So rather then writing multiple get handlers I want to use these path dynamically.

Is there a best way which I can use to store all the route path at one place (not DB) and can read from there only. Currently I am thinking to use JSON where I will store all the path with method type, params etc.

Also please validate is this a correct approach to handle such things or any better way or any node module.

Comment: It is really not clear what you're trying to do.  It sounds like perhaps you want to use Express middleware to be able to examine lots of requests from one piece of code, but I honestly don't understand what you're trying to do or what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's common practice to write different methods for each route.
This makes sense since you'll want to return something different for `/about` than for `/contact`.

To organise this in a scalable manner you should create different files for each route. You can look at [this](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation) official Express.js example.